# Calculate Unpaired Welch-test p-value from 2 data sets

Tags: p-value, hypergeometric-distribution

I am trying to calculate p-values from any two sets of numbers.

I use Welch's t-statistic for sets 1 and 2, where $\bar{x}_a$ is the mean for set $a$, $\sigma^2_a$: is the variance for set $a$, and $n_a$ is the number of points.

$t = \frac{\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}}$

to calculate the two-sided p-value from this formula, where $\nu$ is the degrees of freedom,

$\nu = \frac{(\frac{\sigma_1^2}{N_1}+\frac{\sigma_1^2}{N_1})^2}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^4}{N^2_1(N_1-1)}+\frac{\sigma_2^4}{N^2_2(N_2-1)}}}$

$$2\large \int_{-\infty}^{t}f(u)du=-\frac{1}{2}+2t\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi \nu}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2}+n)}{\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2})}}{\frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2}+n)}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}}\frac{(\frac{t^2}{\nu})^n}{n!}$$

However in my test cases this fails 72% of the time and succeeds 28% of the time.  Why does this formula do this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: One has to scroll way down your code to see that you are trying to compute an unpaired t test. That should be up front in your question. But the question is off topic here because it is about programming, not statistics.

Comment: Hi Harvey, I am looking for a recipe to compute the pvalue, using statistical methods.  All I need is a statistics formula, as the ones I've found online (which are *very* difficult to find by the way) have been incomplete or wrong.  I can handle the programming but I can rephrase the question so it is more formula-oriented.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Comment: Please don't close this as off topic.  This is *NOT* a code question.  I'll rephrase it to a formula question.  I am getting desperate I can't find a formula for this.

Comment: Have you tested your gamma function by itself? How about your factorial function? My guess is one of those is wrong.

Comment: Hi Harvey, I double-checked the factorial and Gamma functions, and they appear to work.  I was hoping that there is some obscure statistics formula/fact I had somehow overlooked, or there was an error I had missed.

Comment: I put the answers on Rosetta code, you can see here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Calculate_P-Value